# Flash Builder 4 code navigation disables for imported maven projects

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flash-builder

has anyone encountered the following trouble with Flash Builder 4 Eclipse plugin: after I import some flash projects from poms (import -> existing maven projects) and set their type to flex library or flex project manually, flash builder code navigation stops working for these projects - you cant' click on method name to go to its definition, can't open a class using ctrl+shift+t and so forth. The projects compile and run fine and code navigation works for any projects created anew in the same workspace.   Any ideas will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to you, but make sure all your .as files have spaces instead of tabs. Code navigation in FB doesn't like tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This bug (defect or whatever you want to call it) is one of a few caused by the diminished cooperation between the vendors of the maven-eclipse-plugin and thus flexmojos-maven-plugin (indirectly) and M2Eclipse plugins (... without pointing the finger at any in particular).

You can however still get them all to work and get back the FlashBuilder/Eclipse goodness:

http://blog.darrenbishop.com/2011/02/darren-on-flex-flash-builder-4-loses.html